# mysql column select and compare

Tags: mysql

Well now I have a table named `user_data` and when members register, a column which have their information's is added to the table automatically as a new row

So I am asking for how to compare these column with one I select
example:

There are 40 column currently in the table a column named `kite` have these information :

```
email,name,country,facebook account,age
```

And I want to find all the matched column that have the same information as `kite` and here I am talking about comparing column data not a duplicate column data because the column `primary key(name)` is changed but it could be there another member that have the same information such as `age` and `country`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem right, you could solve this with a simple join. 
use  `user_data as a` to select only the row `where id is kite`, and then join it with  `user_data as b` to find other rows with same values (important to exclude `kite from table b` , so you don't get it again)

```
Select b.* from  user_data as a
inner join  user_data as b on a.email = b.email and a.name=b.name and a.country = b.country 
and a.facebookaccount = b.facebookaccount and a.age = b.age and b.id != "kite"
where a.id = "kite"
```